# Strange IE only bug on dropdown menu with Twitter Anywhere

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I'm really hoping I can find a CSS expert to help with this odd problem.

In Chrome/Firefox and Opera this works fine.

However in IE9 and maybe earlier versions I have a problem.

To see the problem follow these simple steps.

1) Goto www.spoilertv.com and hover over the HOME button/link

2) Hover over the "Twiter Connect" button

3) The menu disappears.

The Twitter Connect button is a Twitter Anywhere button which basically creates an iframe.

Hovering over the twitter button causes the menu and hence the button to vanish. It's as if the mouse has moved away from the dropdown.

This all works with Firefox and Chrome and Opera.

I'm at a complete loss here :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is "designed" IE behaviour

[IE7/8: div loses :hover if mouse moves over an iframe which is inside the div!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507388/ie7-8-div-loses-hover-if-mouse-moves-over-an-iframe-which-is-inside-the-div)

I've had to replace the Twitter @Anywhere button with a custom button and signin function which removes the need for an iframe

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome#login-signup